# Fill the username and password in NTLM popup in chrome using native messaging

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension, webrequest, chrome-native-messaging

Site: https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd

When we visit the site, the `onAuthRequired` method is triggered in `background.js`.
As per the mdn docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onAuthRequired we can pass the username and password field using the `extraInfoSpec` as `blocking`.

Tested Approach:
`background.js`

```
const myCredentials = {
  username: "me@company.com",
  password: "zDR$ERHGDFy"
}
function provideCredentialsSync(requestDetails) {
  // If we have seen this request before, then
  // assume our credentials were bad, and give up.
  if (pendingRequests.indexOf(requestDetails.requestId) != -1) {
    console.log(`bad credentials for: ${requestDetails.requestId}`);
    return { cancel: true };
  }
  pendingRequests.push(requestDetails.requestId);
  console.log(`providing credentials for: ${requestDetails.requestId}`);
  return { authCredentials: myCredentials };
}

browser.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
  provideCredentialsSync,
  { urls: [target] },
  ["blocking"]
);
```

For reference see github code: https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/stored-credentials

As per the above approach, it tries to authenticate using the given credentials.
And if correct credentials then will redirect to respective page.

Questions

1. How to only fill the credentials and not hitting the request? The user will click on the `Sign In` button manually.
2. How to fill or pass the credentials using the Native Host? The native host will send the credentials and that credentials will be passed to the above approach for authentication.

Comment: Is this client side scripting?  If so, it's a major security concern that your credentials are stored in the script.

Comment: @Taplar Yes, this is client side scripting. Yes, you are right about security and for that I need to access credentials through Native Host rather than hardcoding the credentials in script.

Comment: "How to only fill the credentials and not hitting the request?" - you can't. I imagine that's by-design. Also note that with NTLM/Kerberos, often there won't be an auth prompt at all.

Comment: Why is NTLM in this question's title when your posted code and example only concerns HTTP Basic authentication? NTLM/Kerberos is very different.

Comment: @Dai Apologies for late reply.
NTLM is because the site mention above has response header as `www-authenticate: NTLM`.